# Writing custom validation on mandatory drop down field

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to write custom validation on drop down which is mandatory.

I need to impose certain condition based on the values selected by user. If my condition fails I will make field invalid and display error message to user that selected value is invalid.

I have tried to write the following code but not sure where to write method to check condition.

```
<div class="form-group" data-ng-class="{'has-error' : myForm.duration.$invalid}">
        <label for="durationOfclass">Duration</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
          <select name="duration" class="form-control" data-ng-required="true" 
             data-ng-model="durationOfclass" 
             data-ng-options="h.name for h in availableDurations()">
            <option value="">-- Välj --</option>                
          </select>
        </div>
         <label class="text-danger" data-ng-show="myForm.duration.$error.isValid" for="imei">Selected value is invalid</label>
      </div>
```

Can some one help me.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend either including, in your controller, $rootScope.$watch('object', validate) (this is slow; the following option is better), or including this on the select:

```
<select ... ng-change="validate()">
```

Then, in your controller, $scope.validate would set or unset a flag, which controls whether the form 1. is displayed as valid and 2. is submittable, 3. whether the error message is visible.

Hope that helps!